# How to set SciPy interpolator to preserve the data most accurately?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, linear-interpolation

This is an (x,y) plot I have of a vehicle's position data every 0.1 seconds. The total set is around 500 points.

[image: original data]

I read other solutions about interpolating with SciPy ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52014197/how-to-interpolate-a-2d-curve-in-python) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46207821/trying-to-understand-scipy-and-numpy-interpolation)), but it seems that SciPy interpolates at even intervals by default. Below is my current code:

```
def reduce_dataset(x_list, y_list, num_interpolation_points):
    points = np.array([x_list, y_list]).T 
    distance = np.cumsum( np.sqrt(np.sum( np.diff(points, axis=0)**2, axis=1 )) )
    distance = np.insert(distance, 0, 0)/distance[-1]
    interpolator =  interp1d(distance, points, kind='quadratic', axis=0)
    results = interpolator(np.linspace(0, 1, num_interpolation_points)).T.tolist()
    new_xs = results[0]
    new_ys = results[1]
    return new_xs, new_ys



xs, ys = reduce_dataset(xs,ys, 50)
colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(ys)))
i = 0
for y, c in zip(ys, colors):
    plt.scatter(xs[i], y, color=c)
    i += 1
```

It produces this output:

[image: interpolator]

This is decent, but I want to set the interpolator to try and place more points in the places that are hardest to linearly interpolate, and place less points in areas that can be easily reconstructed with an interpolated line.

Notice how in the second image, the final point appears to suddenly "jump" from the previous one. And the middle section seems a bit redundant, since many of those points fall in a perfectly straight line. This is not the most efficient use of 50 points for something that is to be reconstructed as accurately as possible using linear interpolation.

I made this manually, but I am looking for something like this, where the algorithm is smart enough to place points very densely in places where the data changes non-linearly:

[image]

This way, the data can be interpolated with a higher degree of accuracy. The large gaps between points in this graph can be very accurately interpolated with a simple line, whereas the dense clusters require much more frequent sampling.
I have read into the [interpolator docs on SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html), but can't seem to find any generator or setting that can do this.

I have tried using "slinear" and "cubic" interpolation as well, but it seems to still sample at even intervals rather than grouping points where they are needed most.

Is this something SciPy can do, or should I use something like an SKLearn ML algorithm for a job like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are confused between the interpolator object that is constructed by `interp1d`, and the actual interpolated coordinates that are the final result you want.

> it seems that SciPy interpolates at even intervals by default

`interp1d` returns an interpolator object that is built from the `x` and `y` coordinates you provide. Those do not have to be evenly spaced at all.

Then, you provide to this interpolator `xnew` values that define where the interpolator will reconstruct your signal. This is where you have to specify if you want evenly spaced or not: `results = interpolator(np.linspace(0, 1, num_interpolation_points)).T.tolist()`. Notice the call to `np.linspace`, which literally means "linearly spaced values".

Replace this by `np.logspace()` to have logarithmically spaced value, or by something else:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate fake data
x = np.linspace(1, 3, 1000)
y = (x - 2)**3

# interpolation
interpolator = interp1d(x, y)

# different xnews
N = 20
xnew_linspace = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), N)  # linearly spaced
xnew_logspace = np.logspace(np.log10(x.min()), np.log10(x.max()), N)  # log spaced

# spacing based on curvature
gradient = np.gradient(y, x)
second_gradient = np.gradient(gradient, x)
curvature = np.abs(second_gradient) / (1 + gradient**2)**(3 / 2)
idx = np.round(np.linspace(0, len(curvature) - 1, N)).astype(int)
epsilon = 1e-1

a = (0.99 * x.max() - x.min()) / np.sum(1 / (curvature[idx] + epsilon))
xnew_curvature = np.insert(x.min() + np.cumsum(a / (curvature[idx] + epsilon)), 0, x.min())

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 2, layout='constrained', sharex=True, sharey=True)

axarr[0, 0].plot(x, y)
for ax, xnew in zip(axarr.flatten()[1:], [xnew_linspace, xnew_logspace, xnew_curvature]):
    ax.plot(xnew, interpolator(xnew), '.--')

axarr[0, 0].set_title('base signal')
axarr[0, 1].set_title('linearly spaced')
axarr[1, 0].set_title('log spaced')
axarr[1, 1].set_title('curvature based spaced')

plt.savefig('test_interp1d.png', dpi=400)
```

[image]

Note that I am not sure that scaling on the curvature as I did is the proper way to do it. But that gives you the idea about `interp1d`.

Comment: That's an interesting curvature-based solution. Do you have a source that explains the methodology?

Comment: If you look at [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature) for graph functions you will have the formula and demonstration for the curvature. The rest is just something I made quickly, I would not bet that it is properly done.  You may want to look at how iterative algorithm with adaptative time steps adapt their time steps, as the methodology should be close to want you want to do.

Comment: Maybe based on something like [this](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Numerically_Solving_Ordinary_Differential_Equations_(Brorson)/01%3A_Chapters/1.05%3A_Adaptive_stepping)? Maybe start another question only based on this with a proper title so people knowing about this will help !

Comment: @Liris That is an incredible solution, thank you! I do seem to be getting an error with certain datasets. The error reads "A value in x_new is above the interpolation range." The line that throws the error is the call to interpolator(xnew) in the for loop. I have looked this up and it says it could be a problem with the data? But I am not sure exactly what is wrong with my data. An example set of x and y values that causes the code to throw this error is this: https://pastebin.com/vXWVa7pp

Comment: Yeah, I got that error too, hence the weird `0.99*x.max()` in the definition of `a`. For  some precision reason that I did not investigate,  `xnew_curvature = np.insert(x.min() + np.cumsum(a / (curvature[idx] + epsilon)), 0, x.min())` may return values that are slightly above `x.max()`.  You can check this, and if that's the case, try to decrease the 0.99 slightly.