# What's the function object alternative to 1D linear interpolation with SciPy/NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-interpolation

I'm looking for a way to create a "functor" for linear interpolation of time,value pairs using SciPy (or NumPy) but according to the [SciPy tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate.html) there is none! (Kind of the opposite of [Trying to understand scipy and numpy interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46207821))

The natural method would be [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d) but that has a warning:

> **Legacy** This class is considered legacy and will no longer receive updates. […] For a guide to the intended replacements for interp1d see [1-D interpolation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/interpolate/1D.html#tutorial-interpolate-1dsection).

Following the link takes me to a page that tells me:

> If all you need is a linear (a.k.a. broken line) interpolation, you can use the [numpy.interp](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html#numpy.interp) routine.

The problem is, these are not at all equivalent. `numpy.interp` requires me to know the points beforehand, and does not return a function that can be used to look up the interpolated values.

Meanwhile, SciPy has a number of other interpolation methods that all return a *function* (or a function object) such as [`CubicSpline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline) or [`PchipInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator).

What's the easy way to construct a function or object similar to what `PchipInterpolator` returns, but for simple linear interpolation now that `interp1d` is deprecated?

Comment: Does the 2 stage use of `interp1d` save evaluation time compared to `np.interp`?  I can imagine a spline interpolator having more of a setup time, but not linear.  But I haven't paid much attention to the reasons for removing these legacy versions. Also, later when you have the points, how many do you seek at a time?  Just one?  A large array of points?  Does that make a difference in evaluation time and conveniece?

Comment: interp1d has heaps and heaps of python overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline.html#scipy.interpolate.make_interp_spline) with `k=1` for linear interpolation.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline, interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 10)
y = np.cos(x**2)/(x+1)

x_fine = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
y_np = np.interp(x_fine, x, y)
f_sp1 = make_interp_spline(x, y, k=1)
y_sp1 = f_sp1(x_fine)
f_sp2 = interp1d(x, y)
y_sp2 = f_sp2(x_fine)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, ".", label="Original")
ax.plot(x_fine, y_np, label="Numpy")
ax.plot(x_fine, y_sp1, label="Scipy (make_interp_spline)")
ax.plot(x_fine, y_sp2, label="Scipy (interp1d)")
ax.legend()
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Iteresting, of these three `np.interp` is by far the fastest, even when I don't include the 'setup' time for the others.

Comment: Which is one reason why the recommendation is np.interp.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap `numpy.interp` in a function if you need to. Recreating the [example in the official documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) using `numpy.interp`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

x = np.arange(0, 10)
y = np.exp(-x/3.0)

f1 = interpolate.interp1d(x, y)
def f2(i):
    return np.interp(i, x, y)

xnew = np.arange(0, 9, 0.1)
np.isclose(f1(xnew), f2(xnew))    # Returns True
```

You may add the data points inside the function definition and construct "functors" for each case you have.

Alternatively:

```
from functools import partial

f2 = partial(np.interp, xp=x, fp=y)
```

You can even create a "functor", similar to `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`:

```
from functools import partial

def interp1d(x, y):
    return partial(np.interp, xp=x, fp=y)

f2 = interp1d(x, y)
```